# Join two tables with one common key in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables:

Table 1

```
id  app_name  app_id
1    name1    12001
2    name2    12002
3    name2    12002
3    name3    12003
```

And second

Table 2

```
id  app_id
1   22001
2   22002
3   12003
4   22002
```

How can I show data from this tables for app_id's that are same?

In this example correct SQL should show

```
name3 12003
```

I already tried all types of JOIN and also `select * from table1, table2 where table1.app_id=table2.app_id`, but it seems that I am missing something simple.

---

**CORRECT ANSWER**

Unprintable symbol that appeared after clipboard copying data for database inserting led to this problem. Column values were not identical in two tables. It can be checked by making SQL dump and examinig it manually or with hex editor.

Comment: You indicate that you are not seeing what you want.  What is happening instead?

Comment: Your query works for me. What does your script show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.app_name, Table1.app_id
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.app_id = Table2.app_id
```

Comment: +1 because this is the correct answer as the question is asked, but if you notice he has actually already tried this. The problem is likely with his table structure.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Agreed.  I noticed that too; that's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: Still see empty result, already tried this before. May be, it's some sort of mistake in other area, wrong database, not similar id's, but can't find it right now.

Comment: @user539594: Are you *absolutely* sure that the tables have the data you detailed in the post?  If there is any difference in the `app_id` columns that you are trying to join, you won't get rows back you are looking for.

Comment: @user539594: Also, please provide the `CREATE TABLE` scripts that @Mark Byers requested as an edit to your post.  It could be a data type issue.

Comment: Was creating dump for sending and saw some sort of unprintable character, don't want to open hex editor, but may be \r or \t, that is not shown by phpMyAdmin. Question is closed, without your help I'll be wasting much more time, thanks.

Comment: @Galichev Anton:  Thank you for the information.  Can you update your post so that future readers will know the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

A regular inner join should suffice:

```
select t1.app_name, t1.app_id from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.app_id = t2.app_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you posted should work (although I would strongly recommend that you use the JOIN keyword rather than the comma syntax).

I suspect that your problem is that your tables have not been created correctly. Use the following commands to debug the problem - and pay particular attention to the data types:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;
SHOW CREATE TABLE table2;
```

You might also want to check that the row you expect in the result set really does exist in both tables:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE app_id = '12003';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE app_id = '12003';
```